# Unauthorized WebHook when using Curl and Oauth playground

Tags: php, curl, google-calendar-api

I am getting the following error when I send request to google API using google Oauth playground and also executing code via cUrl function in php code.

> Unauthorized WebHook callback channel : "https://example.com/" . Getting 401 error code for reason "push.webhookUrlUnauthorized"

```
$url = sprintf("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/%s/events/watch",$calenderId );
    /* setup the POST parameters */    

    $fields = json_encode(array(
        'id'        => "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab",
        'type'      => "web_hook",
        'address'   => "https://example.com/"
        ));
    echo $fields;exit;

    /* setup POST headers */
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . 'auth_token_for_current_user';

    /* send POST request */
    $channel = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
    $response = curl_exec($channel);
```

**Expected result:**

```
    {
      "kind": "api#channel",
      "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab"", // ID you specified for this channel.
      "resourceId": "o3hgv1538sdjfh", // ID of the watched resource.
      "resourceUri": "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_calendar@gmail.com/events", // Version-specific ID of the watched resource.
      "token": "target=myApp-myCalendarChannelDest", // Present only if one was provided.
      "expiration": 1426325213000, // Actual expiration time as Unix timestamp (in ms), if applicable.
    }
```

**Actual results:**

```
    Www-authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error=invalid_token
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 401, 
        "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://example.com/", 
        "errors": [
          {
            "domain": "global", 
            "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://example.com/", 
            "reason": "push.webhookUrlUnauthorized"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have add your domain to the developers console.

How to:

1. Log in to the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)
2. Select your project
3. Under 'APIS & AUTH' select 'Push'
4. Click 'Add domains'
5. Enter the needed domains (Only the domain is needed, not the whole notification url)
6. Click the 'Add domains' button

After that it should work,

You are not going to get oauth2 playground to work with webhooks there will be no way for you to add the domain.

Comment: @DalmTo yes , i added domain in my project and still it dose not work .